# Does density of light power (w/m²) increase after passing a convex lens ?

Tags: visible-light, power, lenses

Does density of light power (w/m²) increase after passing a convex  lens ?  and if so i need the equation that represent that increase

Comment: The "speed" of the lens is important,  the collecting aperture.

Answer (score 1):

You can light a fire with with a magnifying glass because it increases the power density, hence the term "focus" meaning "fire" in Latin.

The power density is increased by magnification factor $M$. An approximate formula for M can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification#Single_lens).

Comment: Who is putting a minus on this one and why ?

Comment: It's drive by shooting. Only the OP should be able to down grade and only with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.  A convex lens can focus light, increasing the intensity (power/area).  Look up Gaussian beam optics.

Answer (score 0):

In general, power density of a light beam will be increasing or decreasing depending on whether the beam converges or diverges.

A convex lens is referred to as a converging lens because it converges parallel rays. But, if the rays entering a convex lens are not parallel, the light exiting the lens could either converge or diverge, depending on the position of the source relative to the focal point as well as the height of the source and the lens.

So, you can determine how much power density increases or decreases after the lens by figuring the angle of the exiting beam using ray optics and a little geometry.